# Spacemacs trying to download anaconda-mode instead of using existing installation

Tags: spacemacs

I'm using a preconfigured spacemacs/.emacs configuration put together by a coworker due to limited internet connectivity on the system I'm working with.  When I open a .py file I'll quickly get an error about being unable to download anaconda-mode

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/anaconda_mode/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) -- some packages may not be found!
```

I'm not surprised that I can't access pypi to download a new version.  I want to use the already installed anaconda_mode

When I run packages-list-packages I see I have an anaconda-mode with a version listed as 20160901.1423 instead of a normal version number.  I'm not sure why I have a date format but all of the emacs packages I was provided with have this format, I assume it has something to do with how they were imported.

How can I configure spacemacs to trust the anaconda-mode I have installed instead of demanding anaconda-mode 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bunch of problems with this also. See my solution on the wiki:

https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode/wiki

I got anaconda-mode to work but in the end I switched to jedi because all the custom configuring was a hassle for me.

Note that for my company jedi setup I had to pip install the following:

```
sexpdata-0.0.3.tar.gz
epc-0.0.5.tar.gz
virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
```